# How to swap two structures

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I was trying to swap the content of two array positions where the array is an array of structures.
My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student
{
    char name[800];
    int roll;
    double phys,chem,maths,sum;
};

typedef struct Student Student;

void main()
{
    Student *st,temp;
    int n,i,j;
    printf("Enter the number of students : \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    st = (Student *)malloc(n*sizeof(Student));
    printf("Enter the details of each student : \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %s %d %lf %lf %lf",&st[i].name,&st[i].roll,&st[i].phys,&st[i].chem,&st[i].maths);
        st[i].sum = st[i].phys + st[i].chem + st[i].maths;
    }
    for(i=0;i<(n-1);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(n-i-1);j++)
        {
            if(st[j].sum < st[j+1].sum);
            {
                temp = st[j];
                st[j] = st[j+1];
                st[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The list of student is : \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s \n",st[i].roll,st[i].name);
    }

    getch();
}
```

But this swapping is not taking place. I have done this similar swapping with static structure array and it was working but this swap is not. I am not generating any error it is compiling perfectly fine. Actually, I am trying to swap it based on descending order. But the output is always just the reverse of input. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please reduce the shown code to a [mre] which demonstrates that a simple attempt to swap two entries fails. Try to avoid needing input for that, i.e. fill relevant data structures from code or use hardcoded init values. Try to visualise in output what makes you think that swapping failed. Manually create the output you expect and compare it to the one you get.

Comment: If you use scanf anywhere and get any problem in your code you should double check the success of scanning, by checking the return value of successful scans.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. With hopefilly irrelevant changes I tried your code here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php and it produces output which indicates that the input was sorted kind of, with obvious swapping having taken place. You will have to demonstrate what you observe. Input was two lines, occurring in output in reverse order, even if output otherwise is odd.

Comment: The swap of structures is fine. The bug is in some other code

Comment: `&st[i].name` -> `st[i].name`

Comment: What is your exact input? What is your exact output? Which output did you expect?

Comment: Actually my input is say for two students then: S1 1 10 10 10   and   S2 2 3 7 9.  Please help. I am trying to arrange them in descending order. The order of output for the given example should be the order of input. But it is getting reversed.

Comment: Please use your debugger to see where your program fails. You might like to read ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your code. Inside the double `for` loop, after `if` condition, there is `;`, which means your `if` does not guard statements inside the `{}` block.
Remove that and it should work fine. See line 3 of the below code:

```
for(i=0;i<(n-1);i++) {
    for(j=0;j<(n-i-1);j++) {
        if(st[j].sum < st[j+1].sum) {
             temp = st[j];
             st[j] = st[j+1];
             st[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```